# How to click id of div using another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have Live chat on the footer. On click, it will open chat.
Another Live Chat button on page top. If someone clicks on top button then also it open footer pop-up.

If someone clicks on this.  `<a id="learnmore-btn" class="learnmore-btn" href="#">Live Chat Now </a>`

It will  open This Div  `<div id="tawkchat-status-middle">`

See attachment for more detail.
[image]

Comment: Please see **[ask]** & **[mcve]**.

Comment: Still it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: If you want to simulate `click` on any element, you can simply use `$('#id-of-element').click()` or `$('#id-of-element').trigger('click')`

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#learnmore-btn").click(function(){
     $("#tawkchat-status-middle").click();
}
```

As long as your `tawkchat-status-middle` has the function that triggers the chat coded, this should work.

Comment: Yes. I am connecting with them and they provide me <a href="javascript:void(Tawk_API.toggle())"> Click to Chat </a>